# How to create a pseudorandom shuffle of a list containing 2 and 1 values whereby 1 values cant appear consecutively

Tags: python, list, random

I'd like to create a list that contains 15 values of number 1 and 60 values of number 2 and then I would like the list to be shuffled randomly in a way that there can never be more than one appearance of the value 1 in a row (e.g., it can never be 22212222122**11**2212

Super appreciate any help or directions!

Comment: please include your attempt(s) to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

Generate a set of 15 indices such that none of the indices are adjacent.
In your final list, add 1 if the index is present in the set, otherwise add 2.

Here's what I said in code:

```py
import random

random_list = []
one_indices = set()

while len(one_indices) != 15:
    idx = random.randint(0, 74)
    if not {idx, idx+1, idx-1} & one_indices:
        one_indices.add(idx)

for idx in range(75):
    if idx in one_indices:
        random_list.append(1)
    else:
        random_list.append(2)

print(random_list)
```

Note:
`if not {index, index+1, index-1} & one_indices:` 
is just a fancier way of saying 
`if index not in one_indices and (index+1) not in one_indices and (index-1) not in one_indices:`

Comment: glad it helps, yay :)